# angular 9 refresh is taking back to dashboard page

Tags: angular, angular9

I am using angular 9 with lazy loading implemented. During development and production if I refresh the page manually its always taking the user to the playbook page. I tried all the solutions from internet but none of them helped me. I also tried using useHash which was not helping me.

Only authenticated people can access those routes so its happening only for people who are authenticated

**app-routing file**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/postLogin/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule) },
  { path: 'gallery', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/postLogin/gallery/gallery.module').then(m => m.GalleryModule) },
  { path: 'alias', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/postLogin/alias/alias.module').then(m => m.AliasModule) },
  { path: 'playbook', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/postLogin/playbook/playbook.module').then(m => m.PlaybookModule) },
  { path: 'taskManagement', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/postLogin/taskManagement/taskManagement.module').then(m => m.TaskManagementModule) },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**My child routes for playbook**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PlaybookEntryComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'blockView',
                component: BlockViewEntryComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'columnView/:type/:columnType/:noOfColumns/:blockId',
                component: ColumnviewComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'exportPdf/:playbookId',
                component: ExportPdfComponent
            }
        ],
    },
];
```

As of now I have not implemented guards, I am yet to implement them

**app.component.ts code**

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
      if (localStorage.getItem('enableocityAccessToken')) {
        this.router.navigate(['/playbook']);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
}
```

Solution to handle when user is logged in -

In app.component.ts

```
if (path && path.length > 0) {
      this.router.navigate([path.substr(1)]);
    } else {
      if (localStorage.getItem('enableocityAccessToken')) {
        this.router.navigate(['/playbook']);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    }
```

Comment: is it happening if the user is authenticated? are you using guards? I don't see any in your code. and I don't see the dashboard route either. or is it the admin route?

Comment: lemme add some more code @ionut-t

Comment: I have added more code pls check it @ionut-t

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simple.

In your root component, if the user is authenticated you're redirecting him to the `playbook` route.

Every time the app has reloaded the code from the root component will be initialized. So you need to remove it from your constructor.

You can control the redirection through your authentication guard and authentication service.

Let me know if you want to post an example for guard and service.

**UPDATE**

In the auth service add the following property:

```
public redirectUrl: string;
```

Inject the Activated Route service in the constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

In the global authentication method (where you are checking if the user is logged in or not):

```
// user is logged in case
 this.redirectUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.redirectUrl || '/';
```

In the auth guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const { url } = state;

    return this.checkLogIn(url);
  }

  private checkLogIn(url: string): boolean {
    // assuming that in your auth service you have a property of type boolean which will be true if the user is authenticated or false if is not
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
      return true;
    }

    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

    // navigates to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { redirectUrl: url } });
    return false;
  }
}
```

Protect your guards in the app-routing module.

Comment: I tried commenting that part, but still the same issue

Comment: I added a demo video in the post, pls check it

Pls add an example I will check it

Comment: you might be calling navigate to that route in other parts of your app. Can you post your authentication service?

Comment: auth service will be called only when I click on login. So it might not be an issue

Comment: indeed. look through your code and check if you are using the router service in different parts of your app. in the meantime I'll add an example for how to handle redirection through guard and service.

Comment: Ya please add an answer I am not able to solve this issue

Comment: dude thanks a lot I got the issue. The left panel reloads on every page refresh and when left panel loads I am making the first header to show up which is loading the blockView child of playbook

Comment: I'm glad that you solve your issue, but I don't see how I helped you in the end :). you figure it out all by your self. happy coding!